# htaccess rewriterule for subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, https, subdirectory

I have an .htaccess file, works fine.
But, not for `/specialsubfolder`. `http://www.mydomain.com/specialsubfolder/index.php` redirects to `401.shtml`.

So, I modified .htacces like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
#part I of .htaccess, performed for everything

#stops part II from execution if specialsubfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/specialsubfolder/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

#part II of .htaccess, performed for everything except specialsubfolder
```

Works fine. The only problem left is to redirect all http for specialsubfolder to https.

Unfortunately, the code below doesn't work (redirects to 401.shtml error page anyway). Why?

```
RewriteEngine On
#part I of .htaccess, performed for everything

#http to https for specialsubfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/specialsubfolder/"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(specialsubfolder/.*)$ https://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#stops part II from execution if specialsubfolder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/specialsubfolder/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

#part II of .htaccess, performed for everything except specialsubfolder
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting error because your code is causing infinite looping here:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/specialsubfolder/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]
```

Here you're just capturing whole REQUEST_URI and forwarding it to the same REQUEST_URI. For eg: a URI of `/specialsubfolder/foo` will be forwarded to `/specialsubfolder/foo` and then again and again same forwarding will repeat until Apache mod_rewrite runs out of default recursion limit and throws error.

This can easily be fixed however I had hard time understanding your requirements. Can you brief me in simple words what you're really trying to achieve using rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you. Based on your answer I've found an error. Thank you so much!